# Alter a pandas datetime column based on next value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this,

```
    id  d1  d2
0   1   2016-12-15  2017-02-08
1   2   2017-04-28  2017-07-20
2   3   2017-07-28  2017-10-19
3   4   2018-02-20  2019-01-21
4   5   2019-03-19  2019-06-10
5   1   2019-05-24  2019-05-30
6   2   2019-06-04  2019-07-22
```

I want to check whether any d2 is greater than next d1, if so I want to set that d2 to next d1 - 1.

I can figure out where I want to change the date with this code,

```
x['d2'].gt(x['d1'].shift(-1))
```

I am not sure how to proceed efficently after this.

Result I am looking for is like this,

```
    id  d1  d2
0   1   2016-12-15  2017-02-08
1   2   2017-04-28  2017-07-20
2   3   2017-07-28  2017-10-19
3   4   2018-02-20  2019-01-21
4   5   2019-03-19  2019-05-23
5   1   2019-05-24  2019-05-30
6   2   2019-06-04  2019-07-22
```

How can I do this in pandas with no loops.?

I am currently using `apply` like this for solving this,

```
x.apply(lambda x : x['d1_shifted'] - pd.Timedelta(days=1) if x['d2'] > x['d1_shifted'] else x['d2'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
c=df.d2.gt(df.d1.shift(-1))
df=df.assign(d2=np.where(c,df.d1.shift(-1)-pd.Timedelta(1,unit='d'),df.d2))
print(df)
```

---

```
   id         d1         d2
0   1 2016-12-15 2017-02-08
1   2 2017-04-28 2017-07-20
2   3 2017-07-28 2017-10-19
3   4 2018-02-20 2019-01-21
4   5 2019-03-19 2019-05-23
5   1 2019-05-24 2019-05-30
6   2 2019-06-04 2019-07-22
```

Comment: I will compare this A with the solution I am using now (in terms of time) and let you know.

Comment: @SreeramTP sure then try with `df['d2']=np.where(c,df.d1.shift(-1)-pd.Timedelta(1,unit='d'),df.d2)` . i prefer `assign` because it supports chained operations, but sometimes affects performance

Comment: Yeah, sure. Will do

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using direct assign from `.loc` and `pd.DateOffset` as follows

```
m = df.d2.gt(df.d1.shift(-1))
df.loc[m, 'd2'] = df.shift(-1).loc[m, 'd1'] - pd.DateOffset(1)

Out[947]:
   id         d1         d2
0  1  2016-12-15 2017-02-08
1  2  2017-04-28 2017-07-20
2  3  2017-07-28 2017-10-19
3  4  2018-02-20 2019-01-21
4  5  2019-03-19 2019-05-23
5  1  2019-05-24 2019-05-30
6  2  2019-06-04 2019-07-22
```